# Microsoft.graph getting compacttoken parsing failed with error code: 80049217 error

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use Microsoft.Graph to access the onedrive files. I am referring to the sample provided on GitHub link
https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-texteditor-js
in this sample while getting the file link(CreateLink). I am getting following error
{"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217","innerError":{"date":"2022-03-21T12:49:24","request-id":"45725ccf-a752-45c3-8208-9040e4177e4b","client-request-id":"45725ccf-a752-45c3-8208-9040e4177e4b"}}}

Do I need some subscription to do this setting or am I missing anything?
Is there any other setting is required to resolved this access issue?
Is there any other way of getting the sharelink of onedrive file?

What I have tried:

I have given API Permissions in Microsoft azure application of which I have used the applicationId in request. I have found one URL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-access-microsoft-graph-as-user?tabs=azure-resource-explorer%2Cprogramming-language-csharp.
(Configure App Service to return a usable access token) But I could not find this setting in my azure application.

Answer (score 0):

Please check below 2 steps to diagnose the problem,

1.Login into https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer , Hit the same API and check access token on jwt.ms and make sure you have required permissions to perform.

2.Also check your token expiry time (exp), might be it got expired. Go to jwt.ms to check token details, check the attached image to see where you find token exp_time.
[image]

If the token got expired ,please follow the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?view=graph-rest-1.0#5-use-the-refresh-token-to-get-a-new-access-token) to get new token.